# Finding Dates that are the closest before another date

Tags: excel

I have four Columns of Data - below is a small sample of the rows:

[image]

Column A - Machine # - I have 3,000 of these unique numbers
Column B - Service Date - the machines get serviced each month, so this column has 36000 values (3000 x 12)
Column F - Machine # - same as Column A.  some machines fail 0 times and some machines fail 20 times - this column has 5,000 values
Column G - Failure Date - the date that the machine failed.  As mentioned machines can fail multiple times, so a machine may appear in Columns F and G many times

I want to find the last service date before each failure date, so ideally I will have 5,000 results that read...

Machine --- Service Date --- First Failure Date after Service

I've come up with this which gets the closest date...

=INDEX($G$1:$G$12,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B1-$G$1:$G$12*(A2=$C$1:$C$11))),ABS(B2-$G$2:$G$12*(A2=$C$1:$C$11
)),0))

But what if want the ***first*** date in Column B before it's match in Column D?  So the result in Column C, Row 12 is 1/7 because the service was on 1/8 and there was a failure on 1/7, which is the closest.  But I want the result to be 1/13, which is the first failure for Machine 1 after it was serviced.

Also, Machines 4 and 8 never failed (see Column G), but there is still a result for them in Column C (looks like it's picking the first item in Column G when there is no match).

THANKS!

Comment: use MAXIFS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Comment: @Scott Craner wouldn't I have to combine it with some sort of vlookup between Columns A and C since the number of elements are not the same?  No idea.

Comment: Nope: `=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,C2,B:B,"<"&D2)`